# De Donder Weyl theory

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, terminology, hamiltonian-formalism

Im trying to get my head around what the difference is between a symplectic and multisymplectic manifold is. My understanding currently is that on a symplectic manifold time is the parameter that "evolves" whereas on a multisymplectic manifold somehow space and time are on equal footing. Is this a correct view?

Would I then be correct in thinking that the De Donder Weyl equations are the direct equivalent of Hamilton's equations but for this higher "dimensional" manifold? SO they would describe evolution on this surface?

http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/de+Donder-Weyl-Hamilton+equation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Donder%E2%80%93Weyl_theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A symplectic manifold is defined as a smooth manifold, $M$, which is equipped with a closed non-degenerate differential $2$-form, $\omega$, called the symplectic form.

A multisymplectic manifold of degree $k$ is a manifold equipped with a closed nondegenerate $k$-form.